# Solving $ z \cdot |z| = 4 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I have to solve $ (z^{*})^2 \cdot z^6 = 256 $
After some transformations I have:
$$ |z|\cdot z = 4 \vee |z|\cdot z = -4 \vee |z|\cdot z = 4i \vee |z|\cdot z = -4i $$
How can I solve $ |z|\cdot z = 4$ ? I have no idea how can I do that...

Comment: Writing this as $z^2\,|z|^2=16$ and using $|z|^2=z\,\bar{z}$, this gives $z^3\,\bar{z}=16$, so $z^3=16\bar{z}^{-1}$.  You can use the result from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006609/finding-all-roots-of-equations-which-solutions-are-different-than-z-0/3006637#comment6201848_3006637) with $m=3$ and $n=-1$.  (In this answer $m$ and $n$ are assumed to be positive integers, but nothing changes much if you allow $m$ or $n$ to be nonpositive integers.)  Be aware that we have squared the equation, so some of the solutions obtained may satisfy $z\,|z|=-4$ instead.

Comment: Oopss, I think I messed up $m$ and $n$.  It should be $n=3$ and $m=-1$ in the comment above.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized that the title of your question is not the same as the body of your question.  If you want to solve $\bar{z}^2\,z^6=256$, then you can simply use the result from the link I gave in my first answer, using $n=6$ and $m=-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$(z^{*})^2 \cdot z^6 = 256 \iff (z^{*})^2 z^2\cdot z^4 = 256 \iff |z|^4z^4=256 \implies |z|=2$$

As an alternative by $z=re^{i\theta}$

$$(z^{*})^2 \cdot z^6 = 256 \iff r^2e^{-i2\theta}\cdot r^6e^{i6\theta}=256$$

Comment: In me question I suggested that I don't understand  how can I solve $|z|\cdot z = 4$ so this is the same problem.

Comment: @VirtualUser In the same way for $|z|\cdot z = 4 \implies |z|=2$ then from $|z|^4z^4=256 \implies z^4=16$

Comment: Ah, I know that I can do this in the same way, but I don't know  why is it works?

Comment: @VirtualUser Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ to obtain the same result.

Comment: Does it mean that I can put module from both sides?

Comment: @VirtualUser Yes of course $$|z|\cdot z = 4 \implies ||z|\cdot z| =|z|^2= |4|=4$$

Answer (score 5):

Addressing strictly the question asked, if $z|z|=4$, then we know that $z\not=0$, so that $|z|$ is a positive real number, and hence $z=4/|z|$ is *also* a positive real number. But that implies $|z|=z$, so the equation $z|z|=4$ becomes $z^2=4$, which gives us $z=\sqrt4=2$ (since we've already established that $z$ is positive).

Answer (score 1):

$$(z^*)^2\times z^6=256$$
$$(z^*)^2\times z^2\times z^4=256$$
and we know that:
$$(z^*)^2\times z^2=|z|^4$$
$$\therefore |z|^4\times z^4=256$$
$$|z|\times z=\pm4$$
which is what you got.
now:
$$\left|re^{i\theta}\right|\times re^{i\theta}=\pm4$$
visualising this as coordinates we get:
$$r^2\cos\theta=\pm4$$
$$r^2\sin\theta=0$$